# Log files - skip writing some unimportant (but frequent) strings

Tags: syslog

I have a lot of unimportant similar (or even the same) reports in log files. I want to have my log files simple and transparent, so my idea is that some strings shouldn't be written in log files. An additional reason is to reduce writings to my SD card (Raspberry PI server).
I'm sure that I saw solution before, but I can't find it now.
Any idea what to do?

Comment: Which logging daemon do you use? Would you be willing to change it?

Comment: I'm using Raspberry PI with Jessie (Debian).

Comment: I have found in my backup how this was solved before: in /etc/rsyslog.conf was lines like ":msg, contains, "Router Advertisement" stop". And it worked. I have tried the same (with restarting service and computer), but the searched strings still show in /var/log/syslog. Any idea what is wrong?